# Hibernate transactional method call within transactional method rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, transactional

I am trying to create a transactional method which calls several other transactional methods in order to save some interdependent db entities.  I want the transaction to rollback completely if any call fails. However, this is not the observed behavior. Here's my code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void save(EntityToBeSaved entity) {
    try{
            for(SubEntity sub: entity.getSubEntities()) //specifics omitted
                  saveSubEntity(sub); //this is transactional
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
        throw new BusinessException("Duplicate Name");
    }
}
```

`saveSubEntity` also has `Propagation.REQUIRED` and `rollobackFor = Throwable.class` , yet when the transaction fails at the 2nd `saveSubEntity` call , the first `subEntity` is commited.

Comment: Very surprising. Could you show the code of `saveSubEntity()`? Also, readOnly=false and propagation=REQUIRED are the defaults. You can remove these attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was generated due to faulty Spring injection, as the service was not instantiated on start-up, causing the annotations to not work properly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is Hibernate can't open a transaction for the **save** method.

Assume that if Hibernate doesn't create any transaction for the **save** method, then every **saveSubEntity** invocation will be in a different transaction due to its Propagation.REQUIRED. As a result, changes of each **saveSubEntity** call will be committed to the database.

To check whether a transaction is created for **save** method or not, could you help me to remove the **Tranactional** annotation on the **saveSubEnitty** method. You will see an error will occur if no transaction is created for **save** method.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the help.  I actually placed a breakpoint, and evaluated TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus() , which threw a NoTransactionException , so apparently the father does NOT open a transaction, even though it has Propagation.REQUIRED. Any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: Because you're using **annotation based Spring Transaction**, I guess you did declared the tag `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in the Spring configuration file of the application context. Lastly, you should check the tag `<context:component-scan>` and make sure that the bean which has the **save** method must be in **base-package**.

Comment: Yes, all of these parameters were correct, the issue was with an explicit constructor call.

Comment: @Manos M: Hm, it's strange that you can call the **save** method while the service bean wasn't instantiated by DI container. Did you create the service instance by the **new** operation or the dependency injection technique?